# NotePad++ User Defined Lang does not show conditional statements

Tags: notepad++

I downloaded a user defined language for Powerbuilder in NotePad+. Everything works fine with it except for that it does not show conditional statements in the highlight. I looked at the XML but found nothing wrong with it as it should be highlighted.

Any ideas of what could be sketchy here? Here is the screenshot of how it looks in NotePad++:

[image: conditional_statement_userdefined_lang]

PowerBuilder.xml <- User Defined Lang

```xml
<NotepadPlus>
    <UserLang name="PowerBuilder" ext="srw sru srs srm">
        <Settings>
            <Global caseIgnored="yes"/>
            <TreatAsSymbol comment="yes" commentLine="yes"/>
            <Prefix words1="no" words2="no" words3="no" words4="no"/>
        </Settings>
            <KeywordLists>
                <Keywords name="Delimiters">"00"00</Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Folder+">if choose subroutine type</Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Folder-">end</Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Operators">( ) . ;</Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Comment">1/* 2*/ 0//</Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Words1">
                alias and autoinstantiate call case catch choose close commit connect constant continue create cursor declare delete describe descriptor destory disconnect do dynamic else elseif end enumerated event execute exit external false fetch finally first for forward from function global goto halt if immediate indirect insert into intrinsic is last library loop namespace native next not of on open or parent post prepare prior private privateread privatewrite procedure protected protectedread protectedwrite prototypes public readonly ref return rollback rpcfunc select selectblob shared static step subroutine super system systemread systemwrite then this throw throws to trigger true try type until update updateblob using variables while with within xor _debug
                </Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Words2">
                any Blob Boolean Byte Char Character Date DateTime Decimal Dec Double Integer Int Long LongLong Real String Time UnsignedInteger UnsignedInt UInt UnsignedLong ULong
                </Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Words3">this parent super</Keywords>
                <Keywords name="Words4"/>
            </KeywordLists>
        <Styles>
            <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" styleID="11" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDEROPEN" styleID="12" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDERCLOSE" styleID="13" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD1" styleID="5" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="1"/>
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD2" styleID="6" fgColor="800080" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD3" styleID="7" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="1"/>
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD4" styleID="8" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENT" styleID="1" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENT LINE" styleID="2" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="NUMBER" styleID="4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="OPERATOR" styleID="10" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="@Arial Unicode MS" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMINER1" styleID="14" fgColor="959595" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMINER2" styleID="15" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMINER3" styleID="16" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0"/>
        </Styles>
    </UserLang>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Comment: Try with removing `if` keyword from `<Keywords name="Folder+">`.

Comment: Tried it but with no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your comment said you tried removing `if` from Folder+ in the XML... but when I use the UDL dialog to change settings, it confirms that it's `if` being in the **Folding in code 1 style** that's the culprit:

- As you had the UDL definition, I see similar to what you showed: [image]
- If I then change the **Styler** for **Folding in code 1 style**, the `Choose` and `if` and `end` follow the folding color: [image]
- If I then remove the `if` from **Folding in code 1 style**, the `if` changes from pinkish to blue. [image]

If you have a word listed as both "folding" and "keyword", it will apply the formatting of the "folding" style, because the UDL lexer looks for "folding" before it does the "keyword" highlighting, and stops once it finds it.

(also, I'd recommend adding `elseif` to the "Middle" section of **Folding in code 1 style**, if you leave the `if` as folding rather than keyword.)

Comment: Actually that was the fix. The fault was on my part since I only edited away the if statement but was looking at the choose statement for changes. Big facepalm on that one! Thanks for insisting on the solution!